# Automatic nice value?

Tags: scheduling, nice

I noticed that a process - here sort - has been scheduled with a higher nice value (2) - meaning lower priority.

[image: htop]

But what is the policy for deciding that? Also, it seems to be a rare event, as all other processes do have the default nice value of zero. The sort process in question uses up to 50% RAM and is in general resource intensive - so lowering its prio seems sensible.

Comment: Good question, but please, [don't post images of text](https://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: @Kusalananda, Usually I don't but I believe the color coding of htop is helping to illustrate the question - and it's an image I saw before, e.g. [What exactly do the colors in htop status bars mean?](https://serverfault.com/q/180711/4346)

Comment: (also, fwiw, it took me a while to even find the `sort` process from the image; exactly because of the coloring!)

Comment: @ilkkachu - "Because in that case, how could we know that the sort process there wasn't explicitly started niced?" - You cannot know, but if you believe me: I started sort without nice and haven't renice-d it while it was running. There two options: either the command itself de-prioritizes [itself](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nice.2.html) or the scheduler does this automatically.

Comment: @miku, yes, that's what I was asking: if you saw the behaviour for yourself, and not just in a random image from the internets.

Comment: @miku read that link in Kusalananda's comment.  the other Q you refer to was **specifically about the colours**.  Yours is about nice values, the colours and exact visual appearance are irrelevant.   BTW, if a userland process has a non-zero (i.e. non-default) niceness then something has changed it, or it has inherited that niceness from its parent.  There is no policy for automatically changing the niceness of programs (although it is possible to write something to monitor the process table and do that - i.e. implement it yourself)